# Right way to update a date attribute in a database?

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am looking for a way to update data input (date format) inside a database.

Client app --> Flask --> Database

I am unsure about the best way for processing that needs to be done within Flask.

Data from the client app comes in JSON and may look like this:

```
data = [{"id": 1, "date": "2022-01-01"}, {"id": 2, "date": null}]
```

Note that date can also be null.

Currently I am processing the date input in the following way. Is there a better way to do this instead of manually checking if the provided data is empty?

```
import datetime 

@app.route('/update_date', methods=['POST'])
def update_date():
    data = request.json['data']

    for item in data:
        # query db object
        example = db.session.query(Example).filter_by(id=data['id']).first()
        
        # checking if input exists --> looking for a better way to do this
        if item['date'] == '' or item['date'] is None:
            example.date = None
        else:
            # convert string date to actual date object
            example.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(data['date'], '%d.%m.%Y')

        db.session.commit()
```

One drawback of this method is that the data input needs to be in the format specified in the strptime function. If the data comes in a different format it will raise an error. But there has to be a better way than to just add anotehr elif statement, right?

database model:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Date

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.Date)
```

Comment: "Never trust the frontend", you should always validate your `data` in your backend before doing anything with it. You can use [marhmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#validation) or [voluptuous](http://alecthomas.github.io/voluptuous/docs/_build/html/voluptuous.html#module-voluptuous.validators) or any other validation package out there.

Comment: I guess my main point is how to deal with attributes coming from the FE that can either be a value (in the expected data type) or None. Right now I can't see how Marshmallow would help me with this but maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in my previous comment, you can validate and process the input coming from the front end.
An example using `voluputous` and defining a custom validator could look like :

```py
from datetime import datetime
from voluptuous import Coerce, Date, Maybe, Schema

def Date(fmt):
    return lambda v: datetime.strptime(v, fmt).date()

# Maybe : Validate that the object matches given validator or is None.
validate = Schema([{"id": int, "date": Maybe(Coerce(Date("%Y-%m-%d")))}])

with_date = [{"id": 1, "date": "2022-08-17"}]
without_date = [{"id": 2, "date": None}]
with_bad_date = [{"id": 2, "date": "2022-99-99"}]

validate(with_date)  # [{'id': 1, 'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 17)}]
validate(without_date)  # [{'id': 1, 'date': None}]
validate(with_bad_date)  # MultipleInvalid: not a valid value for dictionary value @ data[0]['date']
```